# Нужно инициализировать массив char[2] с 36 элементами (C++)

Tags: c++, массивы

Как это сделать?

```
char[2] d[36];
```

не работает.

Answer (score 5):

Правильный синтаксис это `char d[36][2];`, но раз у Вас не получается с массивами Си - используйте `std::vector` или

```
std::array<std::array<char, 2>, 36> d;
```

Для Си массивов можно пользоваться сайтом [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/).

Answer (score 4):

`char d[36][2]` - 36 элементов char, в каждом из которых по 2 символа.
Ознакомьтесь с [правилом чтения по спирали](https://habrahabr.ru/post/100104/) для понимания объявлений переменных в С.

Answer (score 2):

Пока у вас некоторые сложности с пониманием типов (сам в свое время с этим сталкивался) - не стесняйтесь пользоваться `typedef`:

```
typedef char twochar[2]
```

объявили тип `char[2]`.

Теперь объявить нужный вам массив очень просто -

```
twochar d[36];
```

Так постепенно раскручиваются типы любой сложности. Если вы используете C++11 и старше - вместо `typedef` можно использовать `using`.

P.S. но вы говорите не об "объявить", а об "инициализировать". В чем же проблема на самом деле?

Если именно инициализировать - то как обычно:

```
twochar d[36] = {{'a','b'},{'c','d'},{'e','f'},{'g','h'} ... };
```